# Bubble Text appears issue?

Tags: unity, gui, text

I'm trying to make a dialogue between characters using bubbles witth text. But the text appears not clear to player.
[image]

The Cam is far from the canvas 13.5f. What to do fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with Unity built-in `Text` component. The larger the text - the less vivid it is. From experience, the issue is happening because `Text` component uses pixels (a constant texture) to draw each letter, but I am not sure.

The solution is to use officially supported `TextMeshProUGUI` component which gives much clearer results and works well with text size and distance. You can find `TextMeshPro` in `Window -> Package Manager -> TextMeshPro`.

Comment: Thank you for the help and information. Now is more better than before.